# Geotagging not working when off the road

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gps, photos, lg, geotagging

i have LG G2 mini phone with anroid 4.4.2. I have a problem with photo geotagging, it works perfectly when a photo is taken in a place which is marked on the map (for example a road) but when you take a photo in park or a mountains geotagging is not working (gps coordinates are not stored in photo metadata). GPS is always enabled. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the stock camera app?

Comment: Yes (comment to short...)